# jqgrid navButtonAdd response

Tags: jqgrid

How to get a json response from a jqgrid custom button. Here is my code

```js
$("#jqGrid").navButtonAdd('#jqGridPager', {
     id: "btnCustom",
     caption: "",
     title: "Test Title",
     buttonicon: 'fa fa-file-excel-o',
     onClickButton: function () {               
         window.location.href = "/Controller/Action";
         //need to get a responce
     },             
     position: "last"
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace the

```
...
window.location.href = "/Controller/Action"; 
...
```

with ajax like

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/Controller/Action",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(response, status, jqXHR) {
        // response is your json data
    }
});
```